# New msn contact list protocol?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I was wondering if somebody knows how the msn contact list protocol has changed. More specifically: in the old Messenger, if I deleted a contact, I couldn't "completely" delete it using the list that was found under options -> privacy, *unless* that contact had deleted me as well. As a result, even if I deleted a contact, I could still get a lot of unwanted e-mail from him (i.e., massive forwards).

I have very few contacts under a new address now, and I've noticed that I haven't got that kind of spam from a couple of contacts I've deleted. So my questions are:

1) In the new protocol, if I delete a contact, is it *really* deleted (I guess this means deleted from the server too), unlike in the old protocol?

2) If I delete a contact but he doesn't delete me, can I still receive e-mail from him, or does hotmail finally understands now that that's unwanted email?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this Wiki about the MSN Protocol](http://msnpiki.msnfanatic.com/index.php/Main_Page) of interest. Do note that some parts are incomplete

Answer (score 1):

> 2) If I delete a contact but he doesn't delete me, can I still receive e-mail from him, or does hotmail finally understands now that that's unwanted email?

You can *always* receive e-mail from *everyone* unless you specifically block them, and Hotmail's block list (if there is any) is *not* related to Messenger.